# Discrete systems with complicated basin boundaries?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, dynamical-systems, fractals, complex-dynamics

I am trying to come up with the strategy to write my Master's thesis in mathematics. At the moment it is as follows:

1. Finding a (preferably) discrete dynamical system that possesses at
   least 3 distinct attractors.
2. Taking many different initial
   conditions (a grid of them, in 2D case) and coloring them according
   to the attractor that the system eventually converges to.
3. Looking
   at the boundary of these basins of attraction in terms of [fractal
   dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension), [Wada property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada#Wada_basins), etc.

---

I noticed that the [generalized Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal#Generalization_of_Newton_fractals)
$$
z_{n+1}=z_n- a \frac{p(z_n)}{p'(z_n)}
$$
gives somewhat interesting results even for a relatively straighforward polynomial $p(z) = z^3-1$.

Below you can see basins of attraction for a few different $a \in \mathbb{C}$ values.
[image: Basins of attraction]

However I received criticism that the model is maybe too simple. 
The discussion shifted to suggestions to look at some other systems namely [Henon-Hailes system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non-Heiles_System) (which is not discrete at all) and [forced Duffing oscillator](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.490.7419&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (which also has to be integrated numerically).

I am not satisfied with these suggestions. Do you know any dynamical systems that could provide a rich variety of basin boundaries?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe have a look at Y. Coudène's "Pictures of hyperbolic dynamical systems". Short, completely explicit, good exposition, pretty pictures, and a nice start if you want to look at examples of systems with  strange attractors / Wada property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "simple" models, especially those that produce interesting results.  There's no reason to prefer a more complicated model just because it's more complicated.

Since "reference-request" was one of your tags: you might look at Milnor's book ["Dynamics in One Complex Variable"](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8117.html).